# SQL Server 2005 - Query Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, many-to-many

I am trying to write a query using the following example tables:

**Company**

- CompanyID
- Name
- County

**CompanyRelation**

- ParentCompanyID
- ChildCompanyID

**CompanySpecialty**

- CompanyID
- Specialty

The `CompanyRelation` table is used because each company can have many subcompanies under it and each subcompany can have many companies over it.

Ideally, what I want to be able to find is all companies by a certain county and/or by a certain specialty. Now, normally, I would just join `Company` to `CompanySpecialty` and filter on those two fields, but here is where it gets tricky: the subcompanies don't have counties assigned to them, so if I filter on the county, all the subcompanies will be excluded.

If I filter the companies down to a county, I would like to display all subcompanies that are associated to that company, regardless of the fact that the subcompany does not have an address.

To get around this, I have to bring in the `CompanyRelation` table.

Example data:

```
CompanyID---Name---County
1-----------ABC----King
2-----------BCD----Pierce
3-----------DEF----NULL
4-----------EFG----NULL

ParentCompanyID---ChildCompanyID
1-----------------1
1-----------------3
2-----------------2
2-----------------4

CompanyID---Specialty
1-----------Vehicles
2-----------Vehicles
3-----------Vehicles
4-----------Vehicles
```

Using this data, say I want to find all companies in King county that deal with vehicles.  In my results, I would expect to see Company 1 and Company 3.

How can I write a query to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Diagram would be like this (with *Company* being the primary / parent table, and all others depending on it):

Company Specialty <-- Company <-- Relationship <-- *Company* --> Company Specialty

Converting it to SQL would be like this:

```
SELECT
   --whatever fields you want, as long as you prefix with the table alias (p., ps., dr., c., cs.)
FROM
      Company Parent P --parent

   Left Join CompanySpecialty PS
   ON P.CompanyID = PS.CompanyID

   Left Join CompanyRelation CR
   ON P.CompanyID = CR.ParentCompanyID

   Left Join Company C
   ON CR.ChildCompanyID = C.ComapnyID

   Left Join Company Specialty CS
   ON C.CompanyID = CS.CompanyID
WHERE
   (PS.Specialty = 'Vehicle' AND P.County = 'King')
   OR
   (CS.Specialty = 'Vehicle' AND C.County = 'King')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  d.ChildCompanyID,
  c.Name
FROM
  CompanyRelation d
INNER JOIN
  Company m
  ON d.ParentCompanyID = m.CompanyID
INNER JOIN
  CompanySpecialty s
  ON d.ChildCompanyID = s.CompanyID
INNER JOIN
  Company c
  ON d.ChildCompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE
  m.County = N'King'
  AND s.Specialty = N'Vehicles'
```

Here is the sample that works:

```
create table #Company (
CompanyID int,
Name nvarchar(20),
County nvarchar(20))
GO

create table #CompanyRelation (
ParentCompanyID int,
ChildCompanyID int)
GO

create table #CompanySpecialty (
CompanyID int,
Specialty nvarchar(20))
GO

insert #Company VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'King');
insert #Company VALUES (2, 'DFG', NULL);
insert #Company VALUES (3, 'HIJ', NULL);
insert #Company VALUES (4, 'KLM', NULL);
GO

insert #CompanyRelation VALUES (1, 1);
insert #CompanyRelation VALUES (1, 3);
insert #CompanyRelation VALUES (2, 2);
insert #CompanyRelation VALUES (2, 4);
GO

insert #CompanySpecialty VALUES (1, 'Vehicles');
insert #CompanySpecialty VALUES (2, 'Vehicles');
insert #CompanySpecialty VALUES (3, 'Vehicles');
insert #CompanySpecialty VALUES (4, 'Vehicles');
GO

SELECT
  d.ChildCompanyID,
  c.Name
FROM
  #CompanyRelation d
INNER JOIN
  #Company m
  ON d.ParentCompanyID = m.CompanyID
INNER JOIN
  #CompanySpecialty s
  ON d.ChildCompanyID = s.CompanyID
INNER JOIN
  #Company c
  ON d.ChildCompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE
  m.County = N'King'
  AND s.Specialty = N'Vehicles'
```

Comment: This will exclude the subcompanies, since your `m.county = 'King'` would not apply to them.

Comment: Nope, this query works fine, because it do select from `CompanyRelation`, but not from `Company`.

Comment: Still not accurate, though. It lists `ABC` as the company name for both, when company 3 is actually `HIJ`

Comment: This also disregards the specialty of the parent company entirely.